# probability - short question

Tags: probability

In a jug, there are $10$ white balls and $20$ black balls.

Randomly we take out $12$ balls without putting them back.

What is the probability that we will take out $8$ black balls?

I tried and the solution that I get is $0.3058$ just want to know if I'm right

I did it like that: $\frac{30!}{(18! * 12!)} = 86493225$ so $p = {20 \choose 8} * {10 \choose 4} / 86493225 = 0.3058$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean _precisely_ 8 black balls?  Or does having taken out 9 still qualify?

Comment: I tried and the solution that I get is 0.3058
just want to know if I'm right

Comment: precisely 8 black balls

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please show your solution.  It's quicker to review someone else's solution than to do it from scratch.

Comment: i did it like that:
{frac{30!}{(18! * 12!)} = 86493225
p = {20 \choose 8} * {10 \choose 4} / 86493225 = 0.3058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \frac {{20 \choose 8} \cdot {10 \choose 4}}{30 \choose 12} \approx 0.305$

I think this may be very self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps confirming your solution:

\begin{equation*}
P = \frac{\text{#favorable cases}}{\text{#possible cases}} = \frac{\binom{20}{8}\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{30}{12}} = 0.3058
\end{equation*}